# Website login: unspecified error when using getElementById

Tags: vbscript, getelementbyid

I have a VBScript, which I want to use to automatically logon to a website and download files on a daily basis. The following script is returning an

> Unspecified error" (code 80004005)

at the line containing:

```vb
Set elid = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_userNameLogin")
```

Can you please advise what possible reasons could be causing the "Unspecified error" on the line stated above? Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

The entered login numeric digits should be appended to the value `4519008`, which is already present in the login dialogue box, when the website screen is displayed.

After the login number has been appended to `4519008` and the password aded, we should click on the sign in button, for the next stage of the login process.

How could I simulate clicking in the login screen after the text `4159008`?

I am sure the entered element id is correct in the VBScript (HTML snippet shown below).

When the above screen is logged in manually, one has to click after the `4519008` number and enter additional numerical digits. The cursor does not automatically show after the `4519008` number.

Whole VBScript is as follows:

```vb
Dim IE 
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
set WS= WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

IE.Visible = 1
IE.navigate "https://<website URL>"

Do While (IE.Busy)
    WScript.Sleep 200
Loop

Set elid = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_userNameLogin")
elid.Value = <numerical digits>

Set elid = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_password")
elid .Value = <alpha numeric password>

Set elid = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_LoginButton")

IE.Document.Forms(0).Submit()
```

The syntax looks correct! The Id parameter looks correct and was obtained from the website source, snippet as follows:

```html
<div class="LoginControl">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr style="height:100%;">
            <td>
                <div class="LoginBox">
                    <div class="LoginHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter your login ID and password</div>
                    <div class="plainTextBox">
                        <span id="ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_lblSrf">4519008#########</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="LoginRow">
                        <div class="LoginLabel">
                            <label for="ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_userNameLogin" id="ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_userNameLabelLogin">&nbsp;&nbsp;Login:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="LoginInput">
                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$loginControl$wizardLogin$userNameLogin" type="text" value="4519008" id="ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_userNameLogin" tabindex="10" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="LoginRow">
                        <div class="LoginLabel">
                            <label for="ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_password" id="ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_PasswordLabel">&nbsp;&nbsp;Password:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="LoginInput">
                            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$loginControl$wizardLogin$password" type="password" id="ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_password" tabindex="20" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="linkForgot">
                        <a id="ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_linkButtonForgot" tabindex="30" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$loginControl$wizardLogin$linkButtonForgot&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Having problems logging in?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I added a little markup to make your post more readable.

Comment: @RenéVogt You have missed the code from VBScript

Comment: `Set elid = IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_loginControl_wizardLogin_password") elid .Value =` is not included in code block

Comment: Thank you for your comments.